# NSXMLElement *xml = [[[NSXMLElement alloc]initWithXMLString:xmlString error:Nil]autorelease] is not working

Tags: iphone, xml

I have an NSString which looks like this:

```
 xmlstring=@"<DamageAccount><EntityState>Added</EntityState><Id>5555</Id><DamageList><Damage><Id>5727</Id></Damage></DamageList><Time>2011-09-22T11:38:12</Time><Title>DamageAcc</Title></DamageAccount><Damage><EntityState>Added</EntityState><Id>5727</Id><DamageType><Id>5726</Id></DamageType><Description>Bad</Description><Name>Da1</Name></Damage><DamageType><EntityState>Added</EntityState><Id>5726</Id><Description>Big</Description><Name>Fire</Name><Symbol>Fire</Symbol></DamageType>";
```

But I want to create an NSXMLElement.
So I used:

```
NSXMLElement *xml = [[[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlString error:nil] autorelease];
```

At the moment I ran my program I am getting an error msg and my program crashes.

The error I am getting is:

```
Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the
document
ageList><Time>2011-09-22T11:38:12</Time><Title>DamageAcc</Title></DamageAccount>
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with my program?

Comment: Your string is not XML string.

Comment: Sorry,I posted the wrong string.. But know, it is the right string with the same problem

Comment: Just post correct string here.

Answer (score 2):

An XML document can only have one root element. Your example xmlString has multiple root elements:

```
1. <DamageAccount>...</DamageAccount>
2. <Damage>...</Damage>
3. <DamageType>...</DamageType>
```

You should encapsulate these in one element:

```
<rootDamageElement>
    <DamageAccount>...</DamageAccount>
    <Damage>...</Damage>
    <DamageType>...</DamageType>
</rootDamageElement>
```

*(Note: I have read the comments on the question and acknowledge that the poster said they had posted the wrong string, but I felt that this question still required an answer for someone who comes across this it).*